# How to handle API errors in a connected react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to show a dialog when there's an API error (or a 404).

My `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
     error: getError(state),
     customer: getCustomerDetails(state)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
     showErrorDialog: error => dispatch(showDialog(/*dialog props here*/))
   }
}
```

What I'm doing in the component is:

```
componentDidMount(prevProps) {
   const {showDialog, error} = this.props
   if (error) return showDialog()
   // ...
   // rest of the code
}
```

Is there any other place where I can act on the error other that `componentDidMount`? Maybe in `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps` so that container component is not re-rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

In render method:

```
{this.props.error && <Dialog />}
```

Where your Dialog is component with error message.

As soon as error is true it will show dialog.